# How to change the Font Size of Selected pivot item in UWP

Tags: uwp, visual-studio-2017, pivotitem

```
PivotItem SelectedPivot;
        SelectedPivot = (PivotItem)AIP_Pivot.SelectedItem;
        SelectedPivot.FontSize = 35;
```

I have implemented this code but it doesn't work. Can anyone tell me why? and What is the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Try using default Pivot style and templates provided by Microsoft and editing the foreground there for the selected item like this:

```
<VisualState x:Name="Selected">
              <Storyboard>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" >
                  <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}" />
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Grid"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" >
                  <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightTransparentBrush}" />
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
              </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
```

You can look for entire style for pivot item [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299142.aspx).